# How to change only color of a pressed textView?

Tags: android, listview, colors, textview, selector

I'm using this code sheet to define textView's color in different events. The textView is in listView (10+ items) and the effect (color) applies on every textView in every listItem. How I can change color of only textView that is pressed?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:color="@color/text_white" />
  <item
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:color="@color/text_white" />
  <item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:color="@color/text_white" />
  <item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:color="@color/text_white" />
  <item
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:color="@color/text_white" />
  <item
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_checked="false"
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:color="@color/text_blue" />
</selector>
```

Comment: what color do you want it to be when it is pressed? and what color when it is not pressed?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" //<<<<<Here focus us true then txt_pressed
          android:state_pressed="false" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/txt_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/txt_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/txt_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/txt_default" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the xml file, to the textview you want to change color, add

```
 android:background="@drawable/filename"
```